# type-check on function that sets values on a pre-defined interface

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to get type-checking on a function that sets properties on a variable with type RefBasketType

Here's a test code:

```
export class BaseTest {
  __base: null;
}
export class Test1 extends BaseTest {
  __test: null;
}
export class Test2 extends BaseTest {
  __test2: null;
}
export type RefBasketType = {
  t1?: Test1;
  t2?: Test2;
};

const testRefBasket: RefBasketType = {};

function test<U, T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(
  key: K, testC: U, basket: T
) {
  basket[key] = testC;
}

test('t1', new Test1(), testRefBasket); // passes (ok!)
test('t1', new Test2(), testRefBasket); // no error here.(UH-OH)
test('t3', new Test1(), testRefBasket); // error (ok!)
```

As you can see,

```
test('t1', new Test2(), testRefBasket); // no error here.(UH-OH)
```

passes, even though it shouldn't have.

Is there something more that I should use in typescript, or is it impossible even for the most recent version of typescript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the type of the `testC` parameter to be `T[K]`:

```
function test<U, T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(
  key: K, testC: T[K], basket: T
) {
  basket[key] = testC;
}

test('t1', new Test1(), testRefBasket); // passes (ok!)
test('t1', new Test2(), testRefBasket); // error. RefBasketType.t1 != Test2
test('t3', new Test1(), testRefBasket); // error (ok!)
```